# Yii2: Ajax Call multiple parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I am using this code for auto-fill with ajax call without any problem:

Code in my view file:

```
$this->registerJs("$('#dailywardentry-doctor_visit_name').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '".yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("daily-ward-entry/charges-cash")."',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',       
        data: {id:$('#dailywardentry-doctor_visit_name').val(),
       room_category:$('#dailywardentry-room_name').val()// Want to use this additional params 

        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#dailywardentry-visit_charges').val(data.visit_charges);
            $('#dailywardentry-doctor_id').val(data.doctor_id);
            },
    });
});");
```

And code in my controller is like:

```
public function actionChargesCash($id){

        $model = \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['id'=>$id]);
        return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
            'visit_charges'=>$model->charges_cash,
            'doctor_id'=>$model->doctor_id

        ]); 
    }
```

I want to fill the data on the basis of additional parameter `room_category:$('#dailywardentry-room_name').val()` which is not working.

While checking in firefox I am getting the status 200 OK like:

```
**GET http://localhost/hospitalerp/web/index.php?r=daily-ward-entry%2Fcharges-cash&id=1&room_category=6**
```

Still I am getting the values as if the parameter room_category is not supplied.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: add html part also for this $('#dailywardentry-room_name')

Comment: Hi, Nitish Kumar - I have already added this - see the response I am getting in firefox -`**GET http://localhost/hospitalerp/web/index.php?r=daily-ward-entry%2Fcharges-cash&id=1&room_category=6**`

Comment: I think the problem is in the code which needs to be modified - `$model = \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['id'=>$id]);` Here only `id` is used in find and I don't know how to add parameter for `room_category`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this param like below:

```
public function actionChargesCash($id,$room_category){
    $model = \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['id'=>$id,'room_category'=>$room_category]);
    //rest of code
}
```

There is another way to do that:

```
public function actionChargesCash($id){
    $room_category=Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('room_category');
    $model = \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['id'=>$id,'room_category'=>$room_category]);
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for your suggestion - But I am getting a 500 internal server error in firebug `An error occured!
index.p.../create (line 569)
GET http://localhost/hospitalerp/web/index.php?r=daily-ward-entry%2Fcharges-cash&id=1&room_category=6` I have tried both methods

Comment: I have tried a var_dump on `$room_category=Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('room_category');`
    var_dump($room_category);exit;` I am getting null in the dump result

Comment: Hi Ali, Ok there is a small typo in in your second option - i.e. `getQueryParam` should have been `getQueryParams`. Now I am getting the var_dump ok, but still the ajax error.

Comment: Ok Ali variable_dump for $model I am getting `null` that is the cause of the problem

Comment: Hi Ali - Finally resolved with option 1, I have to make little change like `$model = \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['doctor'=>$id,'room_category'=>$room_category]);` that is replace id with 'doctor' which is the column name in ipd_charges table. Thank you so much,you are  **Genius!**