# How to send multiple parameters in ajax call using post request in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a view in which I have a `detailview` and a `gridview`. In my grid view there are `check-boxes` against all the columns. The `detail view` contains the `model id`. Now the case is simple, I want to select any column from the grid view and then on click of the `a link` button I want to send the ajax call, which includes the value of selected column and the model id, to my controller. Below is my view

```
<?= GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          /*'filterModel' => $searchModel,*/

          'columns' => [

         ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d) {
             return ['value' => $d['meter_id']];
         }],

         'Meter_Serial_Number',

         'Issued_To',
         'Store',
       ],
]); ?>
 <a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['ogpheader/viewsetpdf', 'id'=>$model->id])?>"  name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Set PDF</a>
```

Now the `javascript` and the `ajax` call

```
<?php
$url = Url::toRoute(['/ogpheader/viewsetpdf','id'=>$model->id]);
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function () {      

$('#myid').on('click',function() {


 var strValue = "";        
    $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    if(strValue!="")
        {
        strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;

        }
    else 
        strValue = this.value;     

});
   // alert(strValue);
$.ajax({
     url: '$url',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
           data: strValue,// also tired with {strValue:strValue id:id} but it did not worked for me as well              
     },         
     success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
     },
   });
  }) 
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, static::POS_END);
?>
```

**Action Controller**

```
public function actionViewsetpdf($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    print_r($_POST);
    $data = "";
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
    {
        $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
        print_r($data);
    }
    else{
        echo 'no data';
    }
    exit();

}
```

The response i always got is `Array ( ) no data`. I have also looked into [Passing two parameters in yii2 ajax request using jquery to a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834538/passing-two-parameters-in-yii2-ajax-request-using-jquery-to-a-controller) and [Yii2 extra parameter ajax in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517966/yii2-ajax-call-multiple-parameters) but both seems to be helpful in my case.

**Note:**

As per my understanding the `id` is a get and `strValue` is post. So I am confused in both of them. May be I am wrong.

**Update 1**

Image quality is not that good

[image]

[image]

The response in `Xhr` is

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
   array(1) {
     ["data"]=>
     string(26) "99 , 100 , 101 , 102 , 103"
    }
 }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: yes id get value and strValue Post value

Comment: you are going to the else branch of `Yii::$app->request->isAjax`,is your page redirecting after the button click?

Comment: try like this {strValue:strValue} and print get also .

Comment: use comma between strValue:strValue id:id like this strValue:strValue,id:id try static data like dummy string strValue:"test",id:"dummy"

Comment: @madalinivascu yes it's redirects to the page

Comment: @THERAVI ok and what changes should i have to made in my controller?

Comment: @MrFaisal then you are **not** doing ajax

Comment: @MrFaisal no need to change controller code we are just checking ajax call

Comment: @madalinivascu My scenario is to get both the id's and the selected column values and pass them to my action, in the same time it should be redirected to the same action controller.

Comment: @THERAVI ok tried and result is `Array ( ) no data`

Comment: @MrFaisal if you are redirecting to the controller from the ajax,why do you need the ajax for?

Comment: @madalinivascu because as already said in my question I have a checkbox so I am getting the column value via `JS` so i need to send it

Comment: why can't you get the value via a form ?

Comment: @madalinivascu actually the `model id` is only for the `detail view` I don't have any thing for `grid view`

Comment: what do you mean by `detail view`?

Comment: I have two views in my single view.

Comment: never heard something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the default click event

```
$('#myid').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: and? what is the alert output?

Comment: got this error in console `http://localhost:225/inventory-web/backend/web/ogpheader/viewsetpdf/52 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: in your alert?,then you have some erros in your php

Comment: No in my console, alter doesn't apears

Comment: @MrFaisal if the alert isn't appearing then you aren't doing ajax , any console errors?

Comment: `http://localhost:225/inventory-web/backend/web/ogpheader/vie‌​wsetpdf/52 500 (Internal Server Error)` This shows up in my console

Comment: remove all content from `actionViewsetpdf` and only do `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: Changed the controller code.

Didn't change any thing in my ajax and then clicks on then button. 

No response. No errors on console either. No alert box

Comment: paste a screenshot of your xhr request header

Comment: Kindly see the screenshot

Comment: the headers please, thnx

Comment: the bottom part

Comment: Kindly check it again

Comment: the ajax is successful , you data should be data: 99 , 100 , 101 , 102 , 103 not data[data]

Comment: Change in ajax call. now I am getting `array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(26) "99 , 100 , 101 , 102 , 103"
}`

Comment: What would be the problem?

Comment: $model = $this->findModel($id); may not find a model

Comment: It's finding the model while using `print_r($model)` I am getting `Array ( [id] => 54 [created_by] => 12 [created_at] => 2017-11-13 05:26:04 [updated_at] => [canceled_at] => [store_id] => 10 [status] => Prepared [issuer] => 88 [admin_incharge] => Faisal [project_manager] => Ali )` and other details as well